Hierarchical filter on Select tags & Select.Option of Ant Design
I'm trying to create a filter with the goal of filtering the values ​​in the lower-level Select cards based on the user's selection in the upper-level Select card.
This function worked exactly as I expected. However, there is a problem as follows, after fetching data from the API, only the top-level select field displays the name, The smaller select fields display the code.
I had already attached the code and image bellow.
import {
  Col,
  Divider,
  Form,
  FormInstance,
  Row,
  Select,
  Tooltip,
  Typography,
} from 'antd';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useCategories } from 'apis/categories/CategoriesContext';
import LoadingDot from 'components/modules/layout/LoadingDot';
import { filterOption } from 'utils/selectTagFilterOption';
import { InfoCircleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const { Title } = Typography;

interface Props {
  data?: any;
  form: FormInstance;
}

const JobDepartBlock: React.FC<Props> = ({ data, form }) => {
  const { data: categoriesData, isLoading, error } = useCategories();
  const { Option } = Select;

  const [selectedCompany, setSelectedCompany] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [selectedBranch, setSelectedBranch] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [selectedBlockDepartment, setSelectedBlockDepartment] = useState<
    string | null
  >(null);
  const [selectedDepartment, setSelectedDepartment] = useState<string | null>(
    null
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setSelectedCompany(data.companyCode || null);
      setSelectedBranch(data.branchCode || null);
      setSelectedBlockDepartment(data.blockDepartmentCode || null);
      setSelectedDepartment(data.departmentCode || null);
    }
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      companyCode: selectedCompany,
      branchCode: selectedBranch,
      blockDepartmentCode: selectedBlockDepartment,
      departmentCode: selectedDepartment,
    });
  }, [
    selectedCompany,
    selectedBranch,
    selectedBlockDepartment,
    selectedDepartment,
    form,
  ]);

  const handleCompanyChange = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedCompany(value);
    form.resetFields([
      'branchCode',
      'blockDepartmentCode',
      'departmentCode',
      'unitCode',
      'groupCode',
    ]);
    setSelectedBranch(null);
    setSelectedBlockDepartment(null);
    setSelectedDepartment(null);
  };

  const handleBranchChange = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedBranch(value);
    form.resetFields([
      'blockDepartmentCode',
      'departmentCode',
      'unitCode',
      'groupCode',
    ]);
    setSelectedBlockDepartment(null);
    setSelectedDepartment(null);
  };

  const handleBlockDepartmentChange = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedBlockDepartment(value);
    form.resetFields(['departmentCode', 'unitCode', 'groupCode']);
    setSelectedDepartment(null);
  };

  const handleDepartmentChange = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedDepartment(value);
    form.resetFields(['unitCode', 'groupCode']);
  };

  if (isLoading) return <LoadingDot />;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  if (!categoriesData) return <p>No data available</p>;

  const filteredBranches = categoriesData.listBranch.filter(
    (branch) => branch.companyCode === selectedCompany
  );

  const filteredBlockDepartments = categoriesData.listBlockDepartments.filter(
    (blockDepartment) =>
      (blockDepartment.companyCode === selectedCompany &&
        blockDepartment.branchCode === selectedBranch) ||
      blockDepartment.companyCode === selectedCompany
  );

  const filteredDepartments = categoriesData.listDepartments.filter(
    (department) =>
      (department.companyCode === selectedCompany &&
        department.branchCode === selectedBranch &&
        department.blockDepartmentCode === selectedBlockDepartment) ||
      (department.companyCode === selectedCompany &&
        department.blockDepartmentCode === selectedBlockDepartment)
  );

  const filteredUnits = categoriesData.listUnits.filter(
    (unit) =>
      unit.companyCode === selectedCompany &&
      unit.branchCode === selectedBranch &&
      unit.blockDepartmentCode === selectedBlockDepartment &&
      unit.departmentCode === selectedDepartment
  );

  const filteredGroups = categoriesData.listGroups.filter(
    (group) =>
      group.companyCode === selectedCompany &&
      group.branchCode === selectedBranch &&
      group.blockDepartmentCode === selectedBlockDepartment &&
      group.departmentCode === selectedDepartment
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Row className="flex justify-between">
        <Title level={4} className="text-base">
          Đơn vị tuyển dụng
        </Title>
        <Tooltip
          className="ml-2"
          title="Các trường thông tin này được sử dụng để tạo hồ sơ nhân sự"
        >
          <InfoCircleOutlined style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: '#1777FF' }} />
        </Tooltip>
      </Row>
      <Divider className="mb-6 mt-0" />

      <Row gutter={16}>
        <Col xs={24} lg={24} xl={24}>
          <Form.Item
            label="Công ty"
            name="companyCode"
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'Chọn công ty đăng tuyển!',
              },
            ]}
          >
            <Select showSearch allowClear onChange={handleCompanyChange}>
              {categoriesData.listCompanies.map((item) => (
                <Option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
                  {item.name}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        {selectedCompany === 'ECO' && (
          <Col xs={24} lg={24} xl={24}>
            <Form.Item label="Chi nhánh" name="branchCode">
              <Select
                showSearch
                allowClear
                filterOption={filterOption}
                onChange={handleBranchChange}
              >
                {filteredBranches.map((item) => (
                  <Option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
                    {item.name}
                  </Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
            </Form.Item>
          </Col>
        )}
        <Col xs={24} lg={12} xl={12}>
          <Form.Item label="Khối" name="blockDepartmentCode">
            <Select
              showSearch
              allowClear
              filterOption={filterOption}
              onChange={handleBlockDepartmentChange}
            >
              {filteredBlockDepartments.map((item) => (
                <Option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
                  {item.name}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={24} lg={12} xl={12}>
          <Form.Item label="Phòng ban" name="departmentCode">
            <Select
              showSearch
              allowClear
              filterOption={filterOption}
              onChange={handleDepartmentChange}
            >
              {filteredDepartments.map((item) => (
                <Option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
                  {item.name}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={24} lg={12} xl={12}>
          <Form.Item label="Bộ phận" name="unitCode">
            <Select showSearch filterOption={filterOption} allowClear>
              {filteredUnits.map((item) => (
                <Option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
                  {item.name}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={24} lg={12} xl={12}>
          <Form.Item label="Nhóm" name="groupCode">
            <Select showSearch filterOption={filterOption} allowClear>
              {filteredGroups.map((item) => (
                <Option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
                  {item.name}
                </Option>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={24} lg={24} xl={24}></Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default JobDepartBlock;


this is the component I met the issue
I have try to make an const to resolve this, but seems that it's not my expected.
const getOption = (list: any, code: any, name: any) => {
    const option = list.find((item: any) => item.code === code);
    return option ? option : { code, name: name || code };
  };

then I use getOption like this. Similarly for the remaining Select fields
<Select
  showSearch
  allowClear
  filterOption={filterOption}
  onChange={handleBranchChange}
>
  {[
    getOption(
      categoriesData.listBranch,
      selectedBranch,
      data?.branchName
    ),
   ]
     .concat(filteredBranches)
     .map((item) => (
       <Option key={item.code} value={item.code}>
          {item.name}
       </Option>
   ))}
</Select>

This is the result I get: a blank value instead of a code. (https://i.sstatic.net/X6ol9gcg.png)
Hope that some one will help me with this. I would like this component to work well with filtering and displaying name instead of code as described previously
